# Starting window in android

Tags: android

I want to know what is the actual use of starting window in android?

What does the functions addStartingWindow and removeStartingWindow does?

Is it a kind of fake window that will be shown to the user till the application dispalys the proper window?

Is it created for every application?

What will happen if i dont do a addStartingWindow() call in the application launch process?

Pleae help me with ur inputs.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Revathi Ramanan

Comment: Are you referring to WindowManagerPolicy.addStartingWindow? The one that is not part of the public Android API?

Answer (score 0):

I feel you are looking at Splash screen..

If you are looking at creating a splash screen here is a [link](http://www.droidnova.com/how-to-create-a-splash-screen,561.html)

-Vinay

Answer (score 0):

I think starting_window  is used to runing animation on.
there is the order:Starting_window,animation,real_window.